# Prove that this series converges?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a Banach space $X$ and a linear operator $A \in L(X)$. $A$ is bounded such that $||A|| <1$. I then have to show that $$log(I-A)=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac {A^n}n$$ converges. All I can come up with is that the numerator will decrease faster than the denominator, suggesting the series converges to 0, but I'm struggling to put that into formal proof.

Comment: Should there be a minus sign on each term?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\|A\|<1$,thus $n\|A\|^n\to 0$. So $\forall ε>0$ there is a $n_0$ such that $n\|A\|^n<ε$ for every $n\geq n_0$. Thus $\|A\|^n<\frac {ε}{n}$ for every $n\geq n_0$. Thus $$\frac {\|A\|^n}{n}<\frac {ε}{n^2}.$$

Comparison test.

Comment: You have shown that the series converges. Could you also show that it converges to $\log(1-A)$? (Perhaps by multiplying with the series if $e^{1-A}$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I doubt multiplying can give anything useful; exponentiating, however, can, technically, lead to prove this. On the other hand, we call this series a "matrix logarithm" just by convention.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy ,btw we did the same proof:)

Answer (score 0):

Just use comparison test to prove that the series converges in norm (and if it converges in norm, then it converges=) ): let $q=\|A\|$, then $0\le q<1$. Therefore $\frac{\|A\|^n}{n}=\frac{q^n}{n}\le q^n$, hence $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\|A\|^n}{n}\le \sum_{n\ge 1}q^n = \frac{q}{1-q}.$$

And, by the way, it will converge to $-\ln (I-A)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it by using the fact that $\Sigma_{n\geq 1} A^n= (I-A)^{-1}$, and taking the primitive to get your equality. You just have to verify that when you derive your expression you get this identity, and that the additive constant match.